# Replace one order of derivative inside higher one

Tags: replacement

How could I replace for example:

```
Derivative[2][f][x]
```

by

```
Derivative[1][g][x]
```

where

```
g[x]=Derivative[1][f][x]
```

?

But doing this in a manner that work for all cases (all combinations of mixed derivates and multiple variables)?

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be very simple:

```
With[{f = Derivative[-1][g]},
 Derivative[2][f][x]]

(* ==> Derivative[1][g][x] *)
```

Answer (score 1):

The objective of this was to use replacement rules with lower derivatives results inside higher ones.

```
Transform[differentialEquationArg_]:=Module[{differentialEquation,previousDerivative},
    differentialEquation=differentialEquationArg//.Derivative[a__][b_][c__]/;(previousDerivative=GetPreviousDerivative[{a},Length[{a}]];Total[{a}]>1&&True):>Derivative[previousDerivative/.List->Sequence][Derivative[{a}-previousDerivative/.List->Sequence][b][c]][c];
    differentialEquation
]

GetPreviousDerivative[derivativeTupleArg_,workingPositionArg_]:=Module[{derivativeTuple,workingPosition},
    derivativeTuple=derivativeTupleArg;
    workingPosition=workingPositionArg;
    If[derivativeTuple[[workingPosition]]>0,derivativeTuple[[workingPosition]]-=1,workingPosition-=1;derivativeTuple=GetPreviousDerivative[derivativeTuple,workingPosition]];
    derivativeTuple
]
```

Example:

```
D[y[t],t,t]+y[t]+D[y[t],t]==0

Out: y''(t)+y'(t)+y(t)=0

Transform[%]

Out: y'(t)'(t)+y'(t)+y(t)=0

%//FullForm

Equal[Plus[y[t],Derivative[1][y][t],Derivative[1][Derivative[1][y][t]][t]],0]
```

Not completely tested, can have some bugs.